# Django management commands is not able to find my application

Tags: python, django, djangoappengine

I having problem running my custom command, as it will throw a NameError: global name "graphofknowledge" is not defined. My file structure is

```
projectFile
|-manage.py
|-..
|-graphofknowledge (app)
  |-models.py
  |-views.py
  |-management
    |-__init__.py
    |-commands
      |-__init__.py
      |-customCommand.py
```

Here is the code for my custom command

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from graphofknowledge.models import TagTrend_refine
class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<foo bar ...>'
    help = 'our help string comes here'
    def loadTagTrend(self, fileName):
        listOfData = []
        f = open(fileName)
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        for line in lines:
            temp = line.strip().split("\t")
            data = TagTrend_refine(
            tag = temp[0],
            trendData = temp[1]
            )
            listOfData.append(data)
        TagTrend_refine.objects.bulk_create(listOfEntities)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.loadTagTrend(graphofknowledge/tagTrend_refine.txt)
```

I added the app name into the INSTALLED APP. It works when I run a print out in the custom command. But once i add the import statement for my models, it will throw the NameError. May I know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, can you please paste the exception stack trace ? Which Django and python version ?

Comment: @Mauro Rocco python 2.7 and django 1.5.6

Comment: Add your stack trace to the question please otherwise no one will be able to help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten use quotes for your filename string. Try:

```
    self.loadTagTrend('graphofknowledge/tagTrend_refine.txt')
```